# Vue composition api: Accessing JSON properties in<template> will throw an error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm learning the composition api of vue. I think I'm grasping how it works but I'm getting an error in the console which I'm fighting with. This is the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FirstName')
at Proxy._sfc_render (PersonView.vue:22:27)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:914:44)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5649:57)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:190:25)
at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5763:56)
at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5777:9)
at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5559:9)
at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5517:17)
at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5119:21)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5729:17)
```

This is the code:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { onBeforeMount, reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const dataPerson = reactive({})

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      axios.get("some URL").then((response) => {dataPerson.value = response.data})
        .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
    })

    return {
      dataPerson
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ dataPerson.value.FirstName }}</h1>
</template>

<style></style>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error since the h1 tag will be displayed correctly and the browser is showing the FirstName property of the JSON. The JSON looks like this:

```
{ "UID_Person": "A1", "LastName": "TestLastName", "FirstName": "TestFirstName", "Birthdate": "1995-11-05" }
```

Comment: As an aside, if you're learning Vue itself for the first time, not just switching from the Options API to the Composition API, I would highly recommend using `<script setup>` instead of `<script>` + `setup()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `reactive`, which doesn't wrap the value in an object with a `value` property like `ref` does. Thus, `.value` is of course `undefined` and you cannot access anything on it. Simply remove the `.value` and it should be fine.

Your code will become:

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ dataPerson.FirstName }}</h1>
</template>
```

However, even if you *were* using `ref`, you still wouldn't need to use `.value` in the template, because, [in the template, refs are automatically unwrapped](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-templates).

As stated in the linked docs, this unwrapping "only applies if the ref is a top-level property on the template render context." I.e., variables that are refs will be unwrapped, but refs that are properties of objects will not be. You *will* need to use `.value` in these cases.
Unless "it is the final evaluated value of a text interpolation (i.e. a `{{ }}` tag)":

```js
const object = { foo: ref(1) }
```

```html
<template>
{{ object.foo }}
</template>
```

"This is just a convenience feature of text interpolation and is equivalent to `{{ object.foo.value }}`."

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I needed to change the variable to ref instead of reactive. I check out the difference again.

Comment: Oh, I see you were using `reactive`. Yes, that has no `value` property at all. I'll edit my answer.